# Search for data and order by priority efficiently

Tags: javascript, performance, sorting

**I have a search-function, that searches for specific data within a huge Object.**

Depending on how good a found entry matches, the finding gets "matchPoints" (or "Priority")

```
var findings = {};
for(var element in hugeObject){
    var points = getMatchPoints( inputToSearchFor, hugeObject[element] );
    if( points !== 0 ){    //It matched. At least a bit.
        findings[ points ] = element;
    }
}
```

Now I have all Elements, that somehow matched, within `findings`.

The function which implements this has to return an Array of all these elements. The most relevant result on the first place.

**I currently use this for sorting:**

```
var priorities = Object.keys(findings);    //Get the matchpoints of all findings
priorities.reverse(); //Sort with reverse order (highest priority / most matchpoints first)

var result = [];
for(var i=0; i<priorities.length; i++){
    result.push( findings[i] );
}
return result;
```

**I have several issues with this code:**

- It is inefficient and probably very slow
- The `.reverse()` function sorts the priorities alphabetically, not numerically
- If 2 findings have the same amount of matchpoints, the `findings`-entry gets overwritten. So the result isn't even valid.

How can I solve this problem in an efficient and elegant way?

**Edit:** I should mention, that although the object where I search is very big, I only get few valid results which matchPoints > 0. In fact, most of the time I'll get only 2-3 matches at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The .reverse() function sorts the priorities alphabetically, not numerically

This is because `Object.keys` returns an array of strings.

> If 2 findings have the same amount of matchpoints, the findings-entry gets overwritten. So the result isn't even valid.

Right, you want to push matches onto the array and sort it afterwards.

```
var findings = [];
for (var element in hugeObject) {
    var points = getMatchPoints(inputToSearchFor, hugeObject[element]);
    if (points) {
        // It matched. At least a bit.
        findings.push({ points: points, element: element });
    }
}
findings.sort(function(a, b) { return b.points - a.points; });
```

Here I'm creating a new object with the number of match points stored in `points` and the found object stored in `element`, but you could store the point count directly in the found object if it makes more sense.

Comment: That's a much better approach than mine :) (Can you correct the findings-initialisation in your answer to `=[];`?)

Comment: Why is it neccessary to use `return a.points - b.points;`? Wouldn't `return a.points > b.points;` also work?

Comment: Opps, fixed initialization. `Array.prototype.sort` is really looking for a positive or negative number (or zero) to be returned, so the boolean resulting from `a.points > b.points` has to be converted to a number, and it would never be negative. I think it's more correct and efficient to do it this way.

Comment: I just noticed you are sorting in descending order, so you really want `b.points - a.points`

Comment: If I put the `points`-property directly into the element-field: Is there a convinient way of removing this property in the findings-array afterwards? If not, I would have to use a for loop.

Comment: Unfortunately not, unless you consider something like `.forEach` to be  convenient.